# Does it make sense to partition my database table with 10,000,000 rows if I have a query that goes through every row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, partitioning

I have a postgres database with a table of reviews that has 15 columns and 10,000,000 rows of data.

```
**Columns**
id
product_id
_description
stars
comfort_level
fit
quality
recommend
created_at
email
_yes
_no
report
```

I want to get every review and put it onto my front end, but since that is a bit impractical, I decided to only get 4,000 using this query: `SELECT * FROM reviews ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 4000;`. With an index, this is pretty fast (6.819ms). I think this could be faster, so would partitioning help in this case? Or even in the case of retrieving all 10,000,000 reviews? Or would it make more sense to split my table and use JOIN clauses in my queries?

Comment: Trying to speed up a query on a 10,000,000 row table that take 0.006819 seconds seems like a fool's errand.  The index seems to be solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This query will certainly become slower with partitioning:

At best, you have the table partitioned by `created_at`, so that only one partition would be scanned. But the other partitions have to be excluded, which takes extra time during query planning or execution.
At worst, the table is not partitioned by `created_at`, and you have to scan all partitions.

Note that the speed of an index scan does *not* depend on the size of the table.

I don't know what your problem is. 7 milliseconds for 4000 rows doesn't sound so bad to me.

Comment: Ok I see. Is it weird though that the index has made querying all 10,000,000 rows slower? Without the index, it took about 46seconds but with it, it took 10 minutes. Is there any other way to speed up the query for all 10,000,000?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Answer (score 0):

10M rows is at the top end of the range for a table classed as "small". I wouldn't worry about anything fancy until you get to at least 50M rows.